# When trying to create an account for Stack Exchange, it won't associate with existing accounts

Tags: feature-request, support, questions, stack-exchange, login

I have accounts on a variety of sites including Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Programmers, etc. I've always created my accounts (after the first) in the following manner: Login, identify Google as my openID authentication source, hit allow when Google asks me if it is okay, confirm that I want to associate it with my other existing accounts.

I am now trying to make an account for the main stackexchange.com site as opposed to programmers.stackexchange.com. However, it is not recognizing my other site memberships at all. Instead it just says "This login is new to Stack Exchange:" and asks me to confirm and create account.

What is going on? Am I doing something wrong? Is this intentional, and I am misunderstanding a mechanic related to how the sites interrelate? I've confirmed that it is using the same email address (I only have one google email account anyway) so it shouldn't be that.

Edit > It appears to see all my existing accounts just fine, now that I've gone ahead and finished the account creation process. For example, if I login, click on my account, and go to the accounts tab: all of my various stack exchange accounts can be seen. So I guess my issue is: "That seemed a tad bit confusing when maybe it should not have been."

Answer (score 1):

The main https://stackexchange.com/ website is just a "portal" without any real contents of its own.

It just coordinates all the data available from all the sites your account is associated with.

So, there's nothing to associate with as it's not a "real" site by its own.